# Joomla 3.3.6: Frontpage giving internal server error 500

Tags: php, joomla, internal-server-error

I have a joomla site and I tried to install Akeeba Backup component but it was not installed due to post_max_size limit. After that I have tried to install it via directory option in joomla and changed the permissions of "tmp" folder. but the path was not correct and the component was not installed. 
Now my admin panel is working fine but front end gives 500 internal server error. I have not changed `.htaccess` file it is the same. And if I put any other file like "`index.html`" or any other file I can access it. But joomla is not working.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have either an incorrect /tmp file path or the incorrect permissions. Is this a live or local server? Can you replicate the issue locally?

Turn on error reporting in your admin area and see if there are any errors displayed.

In admin area check System Information > Directory Permissions and make sure status is writeable.

Check the permissions of all of your files/directories - especially the /tmp.

- Files should be 644
- Directories should be 755

There is additional info [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Why_can't_you_install_any_extensions%3F)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's the other way around. Directories should be 755 and files should be 644.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same with Joomla 3.6.2. The issue was/is caused by my cache folder (there is one in the joomla project root folder and another in the Administrator folder!). When the cache folder (inside my freshly installed Joomla) do not have write permissions (it seamed it must have 770 instead of 750) , then I got an error 500. Another option might work is to use an FTP account during the initial setup.